# When my object is called via HAML it tries to trigger Active Record instead of just calling a method

Tags: ruby, activerecord, methods, sinatra, haml

I have the following HAML snippet being called when constructing an email to send to the user.

```
%p
  Please <a href="#{base_url}/verify/#{user.primary_email.email}/#{user.registration_token}">click this link to confirm your email address</a>. You will then be logged in and can choose a password and continue the process of confirming your identity.
```

The user object defines the method primary_email

```
def primary_email()
  result = self.emails.first(:conditions => {:primary => true})
  puts "DEBUG: No Primary Email address found." unless result
  puts "DEBUG: Primary Email address found was #{result.email}" if result
  return result
end
```

but I get the error message

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `primary_email' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x10f0d3a58>:
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:374:in `method_missing'
 ./views/user_notifications/confirm_registration.haml:30:in `__tilt_2272398620'
 ./views/user_notifications/confirm_registration.haml:-7:in `instance_eval'
 ./views/user_notifications/confirm_registration.haml:-7:in `__tilt_2272398620'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:140:in `call'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:140:in `cached_evaluate'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:127:in `evaluate'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/haml.rb:24:in `evaluate'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:563:in `render'
 /Users/davesag/src/git/showpony3/rack/ruby/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:463:in `haml'
 ./showpony.rb:256:in `build_messge_for'
```

In my simple unit test I test the primary_email method

```
george = setup_dummy_user("George")
assert george.primary_email.email == GEORGE_TEST_EMAIL
```

and that passes fine.

When I trigger the sending of this template it works once and then fails on the second send within the same request. (an Admin User and test user each get sent the same notification email when I test this via the browser)

what's also weird is that in my logs I see the calls to the primary_email method being made. (actual emails redacted)

```
org = {"number"=>"34567890", "name"=>"Test Limited", "country"=>"au", "website"=>"http://www.testing.com"}
people = [{"name"=>"Test 1", "username"=>nil, "roles"=>[{"name"=>"admin"}, {"name"=>"billing"}], "email"=>"##############"}, {"name"=>"Test 2", "username"=>nil, "roles"=>[], "email"=>"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"}]
DEBUG: Primary Email address found was ##############
Sending confirmation email to ##############
DEBUG: Primary Email address found was ##############
Sending confirmation email to @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
DEBUG: Primary Email address found was @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
NoMethodError - undefined method `primary_email' for#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x10ea44e58>:
```

any clues?

Using most recent Sinatra on Ruby 1.8.7 with most recent ActiveRecord and HAML.

The actual `sinatra` route that is triggering the request to send an email is as follows:  Note the loop down the bottom that goes through each user supplied (via JSON) and sends them an email.  That process triggers the build of a HAML template with the User as a local template variable.

It works okay for the first user but not for the second.

```
    post '/register' do
        content_type :json
      req = JSON.parse request.body.read
      if req['organisation'] == nil
        puts req.inspect
        return {:success => false, :error => "Request did not contain a proper Registration_Request object." }.to_json
      end
      org = req['organisation']
      people = req['people']

      message = "You (#{people[0]['name']} #{people[0]['email']}) have applied for membership on behalf of #{org['name']} (Company Number #{org['number']})."

      @@log.debug "org = #{org.inspect}"
      # do we have this org already?
      oo = Organisation.find_by_name(org['name'])
      if oo
        @@log.debug "Found exisiting Org #{oo.inspect}"
        return {:success => false, :error => "An organisation with that name is already a Member" }.to_json
      end

      these_people = []
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

          o = Organisation.create(:name => org['name'],
                                  :number => org['number'],
                                  :website => org['website'],
                                  :country => org['country'])

          @@log.debug "people = #{people.inspect}"

          people.each {|person|
            p = User.create(:name => person['name'], :username => person['email'], :password => random_password)
            p.set_email({:email => person['email'], :primary => true})
            p.organisation = o

            person['roles'].each {|role|
              p.add_role(role['name'])
            }
            p.set_preference("HTML_EMAIL", "true")
            p.save!
            these_people << p
          }
        end
      end

      # send a secure notification to settings.notification_email
      send_system_email 'Membership Application received', :'system_notifications/registration', {:incoming_org => org, :incoming_people => people }

      # send an email_validation_request email to each user email.
      these_people.each {|p|
        @@log.debug "Sending confirmation email to #{p.primary_email.email}"
        send_user_email p, 'Please confirm your account details', :'user_notifications/confirm_registration', {:user => p }
      }

        return {:success => true, :message => message }.to_json
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

careful inspection of your error shows that you are trying to call "primary_email" method not on ActiveRecord object, but on Relation object

this can happen for example if you are getting your "user" variable in the following way

```
user = User.where("some conditions")
```

because "where" returns not array of ActiveRecords, but Relation object

to get the actual AR object you can try

```
user = User.where("some conditions").first
```

or

```
user = User.find("some conditions")
```

Comment: That's interesting. I can confirm the user is not being loaded via `.where` but, in this case it's being created and saved to an array.

But it is curious that the error only happens when there are multiple `User` objects in my list. The first `User` in the array works fine.  The notification email is sent perfectly with no issues.  But the second `User` fails in that it seems to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not a `User` object.

Comment: Okay just to be sure I changed my code so that it only stores the username in the array and then when generating the registration emails it loops though the array of usernames and loads the user object via `p = User.find_by_username(pname)` just to be sure.  I get the same result however.  The first `p` is fine, the second is a `Relation` not a `User` but only when loaded via `HAML`.

Comment: Are you sure that this issue appears only when you call the `primary_email` method from HAML template? If you extract this email in `these_people.each` loop and pass it to template along with `{:user => p}`, will it work without errors?

Comment: Hi @cug your question has led me down an interesting path.  What seems to be happening is actually to do with how I find an `Organisation`'s `admin` user.

In my `HAML` I can get the organisation from the user fine with `o = user.organisation` and the problem then surfaces with I call `a = o.get_admin`.  The `get_admin` method gets the admin user via `return self.users.with_role('admin')`. This is where I am getting the `Relation` returned.

Comment: The reason it was not called for the first user is that the first user is an admin and so that bit of `haml` was not being executed.  So I tried just adding `.first` to the end of that query but then got an `SQL` error.

Comment: I've posted a followup question now as I have found I can now be much more specific about the problem I am having thanks to your help.  See [In Ruby, with ActiveRecord what is the best way to retrieve an object that belongs_to a parent object, given some conditions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7240653/917187). Cheers Dave

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to refactor this:

```
result = self.emails.first(:conditions => {:primary => true})
```

to:

```
result = self.emails.where(:primary => true).first
```

But, not sure it is the cause of your problems.

Also, try outputting user.attributes in your method:

```
def primary_email()
  puts self.attributes.sort
  result = self.emails.first(:conditions => {:primary => true})
```

If that does't shed any light, I think you're going to have to give us the code for your User, Organisation and Email models, too.

You might also check your database to verify that there isn't a stray column left over from an old migration, perhaps?

Comment: Hey @suranyami, the primary_email gets called okay and works okay most of the time.  It's just in the instance where it's being called from the `HAML` render operation (i.e. from `Tilt`) that it suddenly becomes a `Relation` and not a `User`. I made the changes you suggested anyway, and spitting out `self.attributes.sort` shows it's definitely working when the method gets called. The problem is lower level than than alas.  The `primary_email` method is not being called from the `HAML` template, tho it is happily called in the line of code immediately before it.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound crazy, but try rewriting your haml code in a .haml file so you can take advantage of writing it multiline with indentations:

```
%p
  - email = user.primary_email.email
    Please 
    %a{:href=>"#{base_url}/verify/#{email}/#{user.registration_token}"}
      click this link to confirm your email address...
    You will then be...
```

Don't forget to @instance your variables