# In Ruby, with ActiveRecord what is the best way to retrieve an object that belongs_to a parent object, given some conditions?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, active-record-query

In my model an `Organisation` `has_many :users`, and a `User` `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` and a `Role` has a `name` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`.

In my `Organisation` class I have a method `get_admin` that is supposed to get the `User` belonging to that `Organisation` who has the `Role` `'admin'`.  Like so:

```
def get_admin
  return self.users.with_role('admin')
end
```

Alas this returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not a `User`.

I tried appending `.first` to the end of the line like so

```
def get_admin
  return self.users.with_role('admin').first
end
```

But then all I get is an SQL error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: role.name: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users".organisation_id = 2) AND (role.name == 'admin') LIMIT 1
```

My schema is defined thusly:

```
create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "name", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "username",                              :null => false
  t.integer "organisation_id"
end

create_table "roles_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "role_id"
end

create_table "organisations", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "name",                                    :null => false
  t.string  "website",                                 :null => false
end
```

How would I rewrite the `Organisation`'s `get_admin` method (as follows) to return an actual `User`?

```
def get_admin
  return self.users.with_role('admin')
end
```

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Post you model details not only schema, this can help to see what happens.

Comment: Presumably with_role is a scope you've defined on the User class. Without seeing that method, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Yes sorry I ought to have added that in `user.rb` I define a scope

    scope :with_role, lambda { |r|
      {:conditions => ['role.name == ?', r] }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a scope called admin in Users model

**user.rb:**

```
scope :admin, joins(:role).where('roles.name = ?', 'admin')
```

And the get_admin method should be

```
def get_admin
  return self.users.admin.first
end
```

Comment: While Dexter is obviously correct, with this approach you could end up with more than one person who thinks they should be the admin for an organisation, but the system chooses only the first based on id order.  Another solution is to add a column to the organisations table called admin_user_id and specify the administrator explicitly.  You can specify that they must have an admin role with conditions or  a method.